# Draggable Input form

Tags: forms, draggable

wanting to make an HTML input form that is draggable / transferable from one DIV to another DIV.
and the new value of the form is the ID of the DIV ID where the input form is move into.

created an HTML of which the input value will now change. But what actually happens is it gets the origin ID instead of the the destination ID.

the code below was added but seems not to work:

```
var droppedDivId = getDroppedDivId(ev);
input.value = droppedDivId;
```

here's the full HTML code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Draggable Input Form</title>
</head>

<style>
.box {border:1px solid #000;padding:7px;width:400px;height:75px;}
.the_inputs {width:300px;}
#input1 {background:red;}
#input2 {background:blue;}
</style>
<body>

<div id="div1" class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
This is DIV1<br>
  <input type="text" id="input1" draggable="true" value="originally div1" class="the_inputs" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</div>

<div id="div2" class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
This is DIV2<br>
   <input type="text" id="input2" draggable="true" value="originally div2" class="the_inputs" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  </div>

<script>
function changeInputValue(id) {
  var input = document.getElementById(id);
  input.value = document.getElementById(id).parentNode.id;
}

function getDroppedDivId(ev) {
  return ev.target.parentNode.id;
}

document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("dragstart", function() {
  changeInputValue("input1");
});

document.getElementById("input2").addEventListener("dragstart", function() {
  changeInputValue("input2");
});


function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
// Appends the input form to the destination DIV.
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  var droppedDivId = getDroppedDivId(ev);
// Sets the value of the input form to the ID of the destination DIV.
  input.value = droppedDivId;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```